# Trying to close MS Teams meeting app sidepanel view programatically

Tags: microsoft-teams

I developed an MS Teams meeting app which based on documentation, when added to a meeting would have a tab-config dialog for example [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wzUI.png).

After we click Save, we would get the sidepanel view of the app [for example like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqVnA.png).

I am wondering if there is any way or meeting api available to close the sidepanel view or close the app programmatically rather than the user clicking the cross icon or removing the app.

Thanks!

Comment: We are checking this internally. We will inform you once we have any update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no option to close the meeting sidepanel programmatically.

Could you please raise a user voice here:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new